# What is This Zooming/Opening Cinematographic Technique Called?

Tags: camera, special-effects

Some time ago, I wondered about what this particular cinematographic technique is.  I figured out that what's happening is the camera is simultaneously moving away and closing its field of view (or moving toward and opening its field of view).

One example I can think of is in the shortfilm Big Buck Bunny right before

> the flying squirrel gooshes the bunny's butterfly.

(link starts at 3m 14s):

The camera starts focusing on the bunny and then, *without much affecting the bunny*, causes the background to distort.  In this case, the camera moves toward the bunny, while the field of view increases correspondingly so that the bunny doesn't actually appear any larger.

This example is not perfect (please edit if you have better ones).

My question is: **what is this technique called?**

Comment: Particularly, see the last term on my answer.  This is a dolly zoom.

Comment: @AJHenderson I disagree that this is a duplicate, since the linked question "Terminology connected with camera movement" is more general and has a different focus.  However, this is indeed the effect I was thinking of.  Thanks!

Comment: It isn't an exact duplicate, but the question does include the answer.  Note, I also gave you an upvote as this is a good description of the term and should make discovery easier for people in the future.  (I actually had to use google to find it because I couldn't find my own answer with the on site search. :/)